# unclear timeout received on axios call

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, axios, timeout

We get timeout with ECONNABORTED error code while performing soapRequest call of [easy-soap-request](https://github.com/circa10a/easy-soap-request) which uses an axios call.

It seems that timeout with ECONNABORTED is somewhat a valid response for other scenarios than classical timeout. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/427), [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/58507645-uses-econnaborted-for-timeouts-instead-of-etimedout) and [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/search?q=ECONNABORTED).

This is our call:

```
const { response } = await soapRequest({ url, headers, xml: textXML, timeout: 100000 });
```

This is the exception:

```
message timeout of 100000ms exceeded
name Error
stack Error: timeout of 100000ms exceeded
    at createError (/app/node_modules/easy-soap-request/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/app/node_modules/easy-soap-request/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:264:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at RedirectableRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:166:13)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7
code ECONNABORTED
```

We run it from nodejs heroku server.

The main question is what is the root cause of the error?

**EDIT:** After intensive checkups, it was found out that this was a real classic timeout.